# DB2: How to insert a clob with line breaks

Tags: sql, db2, clob

I have a simple thing which I want to do, yet is so frustrating in attempting and completing. I just want to take some value such as this:

```
'a value with
line breaks'
```

And insert it into a `CLOB` field and retain the line breaks in DB2. Something like this statement

```
insert into some_table (the_clob_field) VALUES('a value with
line breaks');
```

causes `a value with line breaks` to be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is

```
insert into some_table (the_clob_field) VALUES('a value with ' || chr(10)
||'line breaks');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into sometable the_clob_column values(?);
```

Then set the parameter to point to your text object.